# Linear equation with 3 equal signs

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is my linear equation:

Solve for p:

$\frac{5}{6} = \frac{n}{72} = \frac{m+n}{84} = \frac{p-m}{120}$

How am I supposed to solve for this 1 variable when there are multiple equal signs and 3 variables.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint: approach it in steps.

1. You can use the equation $\frac{5}{6}=\frac{n}{72}$ to solve for $n$.
2. You can use the equation $\frac{n}{72}=\frac{m+n}{84}$ to solve for $m$.

Can you see where this is going?

Comment: Then I can use the equation $\frac{m+n}{84} = \frac{p-m}{120}$ to solve for $p$

Comment: @caters Yes, that's it.